# Emmet não sugere tag no sublime text

Tags: html, css, sublime-text

Antes quando eu usava o plug in emmet no sublime text ele sugeria a tag so de vc por as primeiras letras da tag porem não ta sugerindo mais, alguem sabe o motivo ? ou como posso alterar isso ? queria pra ele sugerir e completar ao dar enter.

obs: no css ele sugere normal somente no html que ele nao sugere somente se abrir as chaves

Answer (score -2):

1 feche o st3

2 renomeie 0_package_control_loader.sublime-package para 0_package_control_loader.sublime-package.bak (ou mova o arquivo para um backup)
(pasta para ubuntu: /home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/0_package_control_loader.sublime-package)

3 inicie st3
(file 0_package_control_loader.sublime-package vai ser criado automaticamente -> emmet volta a funcionar)